# PHP_XLSXWriter Download File Error

Tags: php

I am using the PHP_XLSXWriter Library to download an xlsx file when I call `$writer->writeToStdOut();` function I am getting an error.

```
 This site can’t be reached
```

However, it is working in localhost.

Comment: sounds like a networking error, try and access the host from your remote server manually